# Create folder inside site assets

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, app

How can i create a folder inside site assets from a app?

Here is my code, it says that folder item is undefined.

```
var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var hostWebContext = new SP.ClientContext(getRelativeUrlFromAbsolute(hostUrl));

var folderCreation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
folderCreation.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
folderCreation.set_leafName("Scripts");

var targetPath = hostWebContext.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("SiteAssets");
hostWebContext.load(targetPath);

var folderItem = targetPath.addItem(folderCreation);

folderItem.update();
hostWebContext.load(folderItem);
```